# Can this function be simplified (made more "fast")?

Tags: scheme, lisp, computation-theory

I was wondering if this is the fastest possible version of this function.

```
(defun foo (x y)
  (cond 
   ;if x = 0, return y+1
   ((zp x) (+ 1 y)) 
   ;if y = 0, return foo on decrement x and 1
   ((zp y) (foo (- x 1) 1)) 
   ;else run foo on decrement x and y = (foo x (- y 1))
   (t (foo (- x 1) (foo x (- y 1))))))
```

When I run this, I usually get stack overflow error, so I am trying to figure out a way to compute something like (foo 3 1000000) without using the computer.

From analyzing the function I think it is embedded foo in the recursive case that causes the overflow in (foo 3 1000000). But since you are decrementing y would the number of steps just equal y?

edit: removed lie from comments

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: You are either lying in your comments ;), or your code has a bug. In the second case you're _not_ returning y + 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12 years ago I wrote this:

```
(defun ackermann (m n)
  (declare (fixnum m n) (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))
  (let ((memo (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
        (ncal 0) (nhit 0))
    (labels ((ack (aa bb)
               (incf ncal)
               (cond ((zerop aa) (1+ bb))
                     ((= 1 aa) (+ 2 bb))
                     ((= 2 aa) (+ 3 (* 2 bb)))
                     ((= 3 aa) (- (ash 1 (+ 3 bb)) 3))
                     ((let* ((key (cons aa bb))
                             (val (gethash key memo)))
                        (cond (val (incf nhit) val)
                              (t (setq val (if (zerop bb)
                                               (ack (1- aa) 1)
                                               (ack (1- aa) (ack aa (1- bb)))))
                                 (setf (gethash key memo) val)
                                 val)))))))
      (let ((ret (ack m n)))
        (format t "A(~d,~d)=~:d (~:d calls, ~:d cache hits)~%"
                m n ret ncal nhit)
        (values ret memo)))))
```

As you can see, I am using an explicit formula for small `a` and memoization for larger `a`.

Note, however, that this function grows so fast that it makes little sense to try to compute the actual values; you will run out of atoms in the universe faster - memoization or not.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually speaking, stack overflows don't have anything to do with speed, but they concern *space* usage.  For instance, consider the following implementations of `length`.  The first will run into a stack overflow for long lists.  The second will too, unless your Lisp implements tail call optimization.  The third will not.  All have the same *time* complexity (speed), though;  they're linear in the length of the list.

```
(defun length1 (list)
  (if (endp list)
      0
      (+ 1 (length1 (rest list)))))

(defun length2 (list)
  (labels ((l2 (list len)
             (if (endp list)
                 len
                 (l2 (rest list) (1+ len)))))
    (l2 list 0)))

(defun length3 (list)
  (do ((list list (rest list))
       (len 0 (1+ len)))
      ((endp list) len)))
```

You can do something similar for your code, though you'll still have one recursive call that will contribute to stack space.  Since this does appear to be the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), I'm going to use `zerop` instead of `zp` and `ack` instead of `foo`. Thus, you could do:

```
(defun foo2 (x y)
  (do () ((zp x) (+ 1 y))
    (if (zp y)
        (setf x (1- x)
              y 1)
        (psetf x (1- x)
               y (foo x (1- y))))))
```

Since `x` is decreasing by `1` on each iteration, and the only conditional change is on `y`, you could simplify this as:

```
(defun ack2 (x y)
  (do () ((zerop x) (1+ y))
    (if (zerop y)
        (setf x (1- x)
              y 1)
        (psetf x (1- x)
               y (ack2 x (1- y))))))
```

Since `y` is the only thing that conditionally changes during iterations, you could further simplify this to:

```
(defun ack3 (x y)
  (do ((x x (1- x))
       (y y (if (zerop y) 1 (ack3 x (1- y)))))
      ((zerop x) (1+ y))))
```

This is an expensive function to compute, and this will get you a little bit farther, but you're still not going to get, e.g., to `(ackN 3 1000000)`.  All these definitions are available for easy copying and pasting from http://pastebin.com/mNA9TNTm.

Comment: Could the tail optimization version be written without the do loop?

Comment: Common Lisp doesn't guarantee tail call optimization (but Scheme does).  If you want to be sure that you're getting iteration, you have to use an iterative construct.  You could use `loop` instead of `do`, but you'll have to write some kind of iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is your friend in this type of computation.  Might not apply as it depends on the specific arguments in the recursion; but it is a useful approach to explore.

Comment: +1 - note, however, that for this specific function no trick will do the trick :-) as it grows too fast.