# Can the standard Ackermann be optimized?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, ackermann

The standard Ackermann formula as written in Java:

```
public static int ack(int x, int y) {

        if (x == 0) {
            return y + 1;
        } else if (y == 0) {
            return ack(x-1, 1); 
        } else {
            // perforce (x > 0) && (y > 0)
            return ack(x-1, ack(x,y-1));
        }
    }
```

I've been wondering - is there a faster version to implement this? I'm thinking maybe there is by using an accumulator or a loop.

Comment: I might ask what is the point? The only real non theoretical use I have ever heard of for the Ackermann function is as an upper bound for an algorithm runtime. Does it really matter if a toy implementation is fast?

Comment: I think the other issue here is why did you ask this question twice today? once for java and once for scheme? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393589/can-this-function-be-simplified-made-more-fast On the other question, you got basically the same answers.

Comment: See also [Theoretically can the Ackermann function be optimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76559257/12597)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example by "cheating". If `m` is 5 or higher, none of the results can be represented by an `int`. For `m = 4`, only the `n < 2` cases can be represented. For `m < 4`, there are simple closed formula's based on `n`.

Everything else would overflow anyway, so let's pretend those cases don't even happen (or you could throw an error or whatever).

Not tested:

```
int Ackerman(int m, int n) {
    switch (m) {
    case 0:
        return n + 1;
    case 1:
        return n + 2;
    case 2:
        return n * 2 + 3;
    case 3:
        return (int)((1L << (n + 3)) - 3);
    case 4:
        return n == 0 ? 13 : 65533;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you one thing... `int` will not suffice for very many values of x and y

If you're going to be calling the function repetitively, you can create a `int[][]` array to store various values so you can look them up the second+ time around and only need to compute it once. But as for speeding up a single execution... not sure.

Answer (score 1):

This variation is faster:

```
public static int ack(int x, int y) {
    while (x != 0) {
        y = y == 0 ? 1 : ack(x, y - 1);
        x--;
    }
    return y + 1;
}
```